# How to add a recyclerview item dynamically when click a button in another activity?

Tags: java

I have a recyclerview in ShoppingCartActivity and a button in ProductDetailActivity. I want to send some data to ShoppingCartActivity when a button clicked in ProductDetailActivity and display them in recyclerview item that creates dynamically in ShoppingCartActivity.

I added addData method to recyclerview Adapter but it doesn't work and app crashes.

```
shop_btn = findViewById(R.id.add_to_shopping_cart);
        shop_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent addToCart = new Intent(ProductDetailActivity.this, ShoppingCartActivity.class);
                startActivity(addToCart);
            }
        });


//HERE IS MY RECYCLERVIEW ADAPTER

public class RecyclerViewAdapter_ShoppingCart extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter_ShoppingCart.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    List<CartItems> cartItemsList;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter_ShoppingCart(Context context, List<CartItems> cartItemsList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cartItemsList = cartItemsList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_cart, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.cart_title.setText(cartItemsList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.cart_price.setText(cartItemsList.get(position).getPrice());
        Picasso.get().load(cartItemsList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.cart_img);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartItemsList.size();
    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView cart_title, cart_price;
        ImageView cart_img;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cart_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_title);
            cart_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_price);
            //cart_delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_delete);
            cart_img = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cart_image);
        }

    }


    public void addItem(List<CartItems> cartItems) {
        CartItems newValue = new CartItems();
        newValue.setTitle("123");
        newValue.setPrice("123");
        newValue.setImageUrl("");
        cartItems.add(newValue);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}


My goal is adding recyclerview items dynamically to ShoppingCartActivity when a button clicked in ProductDetailActivity but app crashes.
```